# Dashes when using partial in Hugo

Tags: go, hugo

I'm trying to build a custom theme for hugo. This is my first time using Go and I was wondering what are the dashes in the code below?

`{{- partial "head.html" . -}}`

Here is the whole file if needed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    {{- partial "head.html" . -}}
    <body>

        <div id="content">
        {{- block "main" . }}{{- end }}
        </div>
        {{- partial "footer.html" . -}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Are the dashes there for any reason and if yes when should I use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation here: https://gohugo.io/templates/introduction/#whitespace

*Go 1.6 includes the ability to trim the whitespace from either side of a Go tag by including a hyphen (-) and space immediately beside the corresponding {{ or }} delimiter.*